# How to delete a row in a XAML DataGrid which is bound to a sqlite?

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid

I got a xaml datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="productTransactionsGrid" 
          CanUserAddRows="true" 
          CanUserDeleteRows  ="True" 
          RowEditEnding="productTransactionsGrid_RowEditEnding" 
          CurrentCellChanged="productTransactionsGrid_CurrentCellChanged"/>
```

witch is initialized like this from a row in sqlite:

```
private void InitTransactions()
{
    productTransactionsGrid.ItemsSource = (from p in m_DbSession.Query<ProductTransaction>()
                                          where (p.Product.Id == m_DBProduct.Id)
                                          orderby p.Date
                                          select new ProductTransactionDatasource(p, m_DbSession)).ToList();
    productTransactionsGrid.ScrollIntoView(CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder);
}
```

The product datasource looks like this

```
class ProductDatasource : AddableDatasource
{
    Product m_Product;

    public ProductDatasource()
    {
        m_Product = new Product();
    }

    public ProductDatasource(Product initialProduct, ISessionWrapper dbSession)
    {
        m_Product = initialProduct;
        SetSession(dbSession);
    }

    //...some properties


    internal Product GetProduct()
    {
        return m_Product;
    }

    protected override object GetDbObject()
    {
        return m_Product;
    }

}
```

Now the user can press "delete" and the selected row is removed from the datagrid. But it is not removed from the database. So I think this is not saved.

I thought that I have to save it by myself. So I tried to find an event which triggers when the user deletes a row, but I was not able to find such an event.

Comment: You have to delete from the m_DbSession and then accept changes to m_DbSession.

Comment: Yes. But I am not able to find an event or a function which triggers when the user does this.

Comment: Then you are missing the event.  Probably the cell event needs modifications : CurrentCellChanged="productTransactionsGrid_CurrentCellChanged"

Comment: productTransactionsGrid_CurrentCellChanged is called, but I cant see if the row was deleted or changed.

Comment: Do you also need a row change event?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow?force_isolation=true&view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: This is a link to the forms datagrid. I use xaml. And there is no UserDeletingRow-event.